# Bootstrap 4 dropdown appears by hover

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

It is my understanding that dropdown menus in bootstrap 4 appear on click by default. However my menu is appearing by hover without me using any additional CSS or JS. This creates a rather big issue for development on mobile. I could create a Jquery solution but im sure there is a bootstrap 4 equivalent fix to this?

Here is a snippet of one of my dropdowns.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-primary py-0">
    <div class="container h-100 pl-0 pr-0">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse h-100" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mx-auto h-100 center-nav-mobile paddingTopAndBottom">
                <li class="d-md-none text-white h6">Browse Product Categories</li>

                @*//FLAT ROOFING*@
                <li class="nav-item dropdown px-2 arrowDown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white paddingRightButton h-100 noPaddingRightLeft" href="/category/flat-roof-materials" id="flatRoofingDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Flat Roofing
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu p-0 justify-content-center border border-primary row mx-auto rounded" aria-labelledby="flatRoofingDropdown">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 bg-grey mt-0 pl-0 pr-0 border-bottom">
                                    @*//only show on screens above medium*@
                                    <div class="colorme nav flex-column nav-pills d-none d-md-block" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdownlinks active pl-2 dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" id="v-pills-rubberRoofing-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-rubberRoofing" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-rubberRoofing" aria-selected="true">EPDM Rubber Roofing</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdownlinks pl-2 dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" id="v-pills-fibre-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-fibre" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-fibre" aria-selected="false">Fibreglass GRP</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdownlinks pl-2 dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" id="v-pills-roofingFelt-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-roofingFelt" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-roofingFelt" aria-selected="false">Roofing Felt</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdownlinks pl-2 dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" id="v-pills-greenRoof-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-greenRoof" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-greenRoof" aria-selected="false">Green Roof System</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdownlinks pl-2 dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" id="v-pills-liquid-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-liquid" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-liquid" aria-selected="false">Liquid Waterproofing</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdownlinks pl-2 dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" id="v-pills-skylights-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-skylights" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-skylights" aria-selected="false">Skylights</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item dropdownlinks pl-2 dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" id="v-pills-flatRoof-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-flatRoof" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-flatRoof" aria-selected="false">Flat Roof Outlets</a>
                                    </div>

                                    @*//only show on screens below medium*@
                                    <div id="accordion" class="d-md-none">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingrubberRoofing">
                                                <h5 class="mb-0 acordionHeaderLinks">
                                                    <button class="btn buttonArrow btn-link w-100 text-left rounded-0 text-dark text-decoration-none font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#rubberRoofing" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="rubberRoofing">
                                                        EPDM Rubber Roofing
                                                    </button>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="rubberRoofing" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingrubberRoofing" data-parent="#accordion">
                                                <div class="card-body p-2 pl-3 text-left">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/classicbond">ClassicBond</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/firestone-rubbercover">Firestone</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/duoply">Duoply</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingfibreglass">
                                                <h5 class="mb-0 acordionHeaderLinks">
                                                    <button class="btn buttonArrow btn-link collapsed w-100 text-left rounded-0 text-dark text-decoration-none font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#fibreglass" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="fibreglass">
                                                        Fibreglass GRP
                                                    </button>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="fibreglass" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingfibreglass" data-parent="#accordion">
                                                <div class="card-body p-2 pl-3 text-left">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/fibreglass-grp-roofing-systems?filter232=Cromar&page=1">ProGRP</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/flexitec-2020">Flexitec 2020</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/tools/flexitec-calculator">Flexitec 2020 Roof Calculator</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/tools/grp1010-calculator">GRP Roof 1010</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/ultraflex">Ultraflex</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingroofingfelt">
                                                <h5 class="mb-0 acordionHeaderLinks">
                                                    <button class="btn buttonArrow btn-link collapsed w-100 text-left rounded-0 text-dark text-decoration-none font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#roofingfelt" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="roofingfelt">
                                                        Roofing Felt
                                                    </button>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="roofingfelt" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingroofingfelt" data-parent="#accordion">
                                                <div class="card-body p-2 pl-3 text-left">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/torch-on-felt">Torch on felts</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/timber-sheeting">Timber Sheeting</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/osb">OSB</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header p-0" id="headinggreenroof">
                                                <h5 class="mb-0 acordionHeaderLinks">
                                                    <button class="btn buttonArrow btn-link collapsed w-100 text-left rounded-0 text-dark text-decoration-none font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#greenroof" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="greenroof">
                                                        Green Roof System
                                                    </button>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="greenroof" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headinggreenroof" data-parent="#accordion">
                                                <div class="card-body p-2 pl-3 text-left">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/green-roofing?filter232=GrufeKit&page=1">Grufe kit</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingliquidwaterproof">
                                                <h5 class="mb-0 acordionHeaderLinks">
                                                    <button class="btn buttonArrow btn-link collapsed w-100 text-left rounded-0 text-dark text-decoration-none font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#liquidwaterproof" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="liquidwaterproof">
                                                        Liquid Waterproofing
                                                    </button>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="liquidwaterproof" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingliquidwaterproof" data-parent="#accordion">
                                                <div class="card-body p-2 pl-3 text-left">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/elastathane">Elastathane 25</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/hydrosil-silicone-roof-coating">Hydrosil</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/tools/flexitec-calculator">Liquid Rubber</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingskylights">
                                                <h5 class="mb-0 acordionHeaderLinks">
                                                    <button class="btn buttonArrow btn-link collapsed w-100 text-left rounded-0 text-dark text-decoration-none font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#skylights" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="skylights">
                                                        Skylights
                                                    </button>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="skylights" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingskylights" data-parent="#accordion">
                                                <div class="card-body p-2 pl-3 text-left">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="#">Flat Glass Rooflights</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="#">Domes</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingflatroof">
                                                <h5 class="mb-0 acordionHeaderLinks">
                                                    <button class="btn buttonArrow btn-link collapsed w-100 text-left rounded-0 text-dark text-decoration-none font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#flatroof" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flatroof">
                                                        Flat Roof Outlets
                                                    </button>
                                                </h5>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="flatroof" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingflatroof" data-parent="#accordion">
                                                <div class="card-body p-2 pl-3 text-left">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/flat-roof-outlets">Water Outlets</a>
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/flat-roof-vents">Flat Roof Vents</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 mt-0 pl-2 pr-0 d-none d-md-block">

                                    @*//only show on screens above medium *@
                                    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-rubberRoofing" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-rubberRoofing-tab">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/classicbond">ClassicBond</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/firestone-rubbercover">Firestone</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/duoply">Duoply</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-fibre" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-fibre-tab">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/fibreglass-grp-roofing-systems?filter232=Cromar&page=1">ProGRP</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/flexitec-2020">Flexitec 2020</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/tools/flexitec-calculator">Flexitec 2020 Roof Calculator</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/tools/grp1010-calculator">GRP Roof 1010</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/ultraflex">Ultraflex</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-roofingFelt" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-roofingFelt-tab">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/torch-on-felt">Torch on felts</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/timber-sheeting">Timber Sheeting</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/osb">OSB</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-greenRoof" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-greenRoof-tab">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/green-roofing?filter232=GrufeKit&page=1">Grufe kit</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-liquid" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-liquid-tab">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/elastathane">Elastathane 25</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/hydrosil-silicone-roof-coating">Hydrosil</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/tools/flexitec-calculator">Liquid Rubber</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-skylights" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-skylights-tab">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="#">Flat Glass Rooflights</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="#">Domes</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-flatRoof" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-flatRoof-tab">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/flat-roof-outlets">Water Outlets</a>
                                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdownsubmenulinks pl-2" href="/category/flat-roof-vents">Flat Roof Vents</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5 border-left">
                                    <div class="py-2">
                                        <div class="advice">
                                            <p><span class="fa fa-question-circle fa-fw"></span>Expert Advice</p>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="/blog/what-do-roofers-need-to-know-about-sedum-roofs">What Do Roofers Need To Know About Green Roofs?</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/blog/tell-me-more-about-epdm-rubber-roofing">Tell Me More About...Rubber Roofing</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/blog/benefits-torch-on-roofing-felt">Why You Should Consider Torch-On Felt</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="/blog/why-choose-a-grp-flat-roof">Why Choose A GRP Flat Roof?</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="/Static/RoofingCalculators">
                                        <img class="img-fluid py-2" data-src="/Content/images/promo/menu/flat-roofing/Flat_Roof_Calculators.png" src="~/Content/images/promo/menu/flat-roofing/Flat_Roof_Calculators.png" alt="Flat Roof Calculators">
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="/category/flexitec-2020">
                                        <img class="img-fluid py-2" data-src="/Content/images/promo/menu/flat-roofing/Flexitec_2020.png" src="~/Content/images/promo/menu/flat-roofing/Flexitec_2020.png" alt="Flexitec 2020">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **navbar-expand-md** class makes it appears expanded by default on medium and larger. It shouldn't load expanded on small and extra small.

Check

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

and

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: navbar-expand-md has nothing to do with the dropdown appearing by hover opposed to click. I get the same behaviour in xs screens to xl.  " Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes"

Comment: Ahh sorry, it seems I misread. I never had that behavior using bootstrap navbars.